# Can anybody give proof about features of phase and magnitude spectrum?

Tags: signal-processing, fourier, harmonics

I have read that from Fourier transform we obtain magnitude and phase spectrum. The magnitude spectrum tells you how strong are the harmonics in a image and the phase spectrum tells where this harmonic lies in space.

But when I plotted the phase and magnitude spectrum of say an image, the spectrum were very weird and  specifically the phase spectrum is very hard to understand. So I feel Extracting information from the phase and magnitude spectrum of a signal  is very difficult .

So let us take any **signal of your choice** (as I am not concerned with any perticular signal) and plot it's phase and magnitude spectrum.

Now,can u extract information from Magnitude spectrum and Phase spectrum of the signal and justify sentences given in the 1st paragraph of question?

Can u give proof about these sentences?

Comment: I don't understand the question. You claim that the magnitude and phase tell you specific things (information), but then you say that it's too hard to get information. What are you asking here? Can you give an example?

Comment: Time-domain and frequency-domain always contain the same information. Some features of a specific signal are easier to recognize in time domain and some features of that same signal are easier to recognize in frequency domain. That's why the Fourier transform is useful and important. What's the specific question?

Comment: @Greg sir,let us take any
signal of your choice and
plot it's phase and
magnitude spectrum. how
can u extract information
from Magnitude spectrum
and Phase spectrum so
that you can justify
sentences in the 1st
paragraph of my question?

Comment: This question might be a better fit on dsp.stackexchange.com.

Comment: First paragraph is justified by definition of [Fourier Transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Introduction). Magnitude gives the amplitude of a cosine wave and phase gives each cosine's phase offset (i.e. time delay) with respect to the zero phase reference. I dispute your claim that the phase correlates with "location in space" (i.e. time delay), except for trivial single-sinuouid signals. Phase relationships between harmonics are related to waveform envelope (shape), not location in space.

Comment: @ThePhoton: This comes FROM dsp.stackexchange.com - see http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/23325/compare-phase-and-magnitude-spectrum-results-of-2-images  pandu isn't satisified with the answer he got there (basically, phase and magnitude of the FFT of an image aren't terribly useful and the FFT is generally only used as an intermediate step in image processing.)

Comment: @JRE, in that case OP should link to the old question, explain why the previous answers aren't helpful for him/her, and clarify what s/he wants to know so we can give a helpful answer.

Comment: OP: I don't think you're going to get a better answer than the [one by @nikie](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/1644) to the similar question that yours duplicated on dsp.

Comment: From a Fourier transform, we obtain a *complex-valued function*. The values of this function have an *interpretation* as phase and amplitude: the argument of the complex number is phase, and the modulus is amplitude. Be sure you're not looking at the \$x + iy\$ real/imaginary pairs and confusing them for magnitude and phase!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

The first image shows the addition of two harmonics (blue, orange), both are sine waves, the two add together to create the resultant red waveform.In the frequency spectrum for the resultant red waveform, there would be only two vertical lines at different frequencies.

[image]

The second image shows the addition of 5 harmonics, and the resultant (combined) waveform is again the red line, and you can see on this chart, the red line is closer to a square wave, it's flatter on top and the bottom, and the steep edge is steeper.

So you can see that the more sinewaves you add, so long as they are the correct multiples in frequency of the fundamental and correct amplitudes relative to each other, then the better the approximation to the squarewave.

Any repeating waveform can be constructed from sinewaves of different frequencies, amplitudes and phases.

The third image shows the spectrums and the time waveforms for two periodic waveforms.
The first is a a square wave and above it is its spectrum showing the harmonics, what multiples in frequency they are of the fundamental and the relative amplitude of each.

The second waveform and spectrum isn't a standard waveform (square, sawtooth, ramp..), I don't know what it is, it might even be a section of waveform for a musical instrument. But it illustates that a periodic (repeating) waveform can be constructed from sinewaves (harmonics).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The spectrum tells you what harmonics are present and what their magnitude is.
The phase chart doesn't tell you "phase spectrum tells where this harmonic lies in space.". The phase chart tells you how much each harmonic has been delayed (or advanced). You have to understand what a harmonic is. If your electrical signal is the most simplest of all (other than DC!), a sine wave then the spectrum is a single vertical line. No other lines are present on spectrum. So the harmonics are actually separate sinewaves of varying amplitudes and the frequency of the sinewave determines where that vertical line is along the horizontal axis of the spectrum, but sinewaves have a phase, which is the voltage that sinewave is at when time is zero.  What the phase chart does is depict how those multiple sinewaves are delayed (shifted left or right on a time/voltage (or time/current) graph).

Two domains: Time domain, frequency domain.  Signals are by their very nature voltages or currents (or perhaps they start off originally something else such as sound) which change with time. An oscilliscope shows the time/voltage relationship

For some things it is useful to think about the signal in the frequency domain, audio is one of them. You might want to know what frequencies are present in the sound, but you've actually recorded/captured a time/voltage varying signal.

What you have to do is carry out a Fourier Transform of that time/voltage waveform to convert it into the Frequeny spectrum.  Doing a fourier transform, generarting a fourier series of the voltage/time waveform is NOT easy.  You have to use a mathematical operation of integration (there are three fairly tricky equations you need to calculate the answers to, all of which use integration. It's not the sort of maths that is undertaken at school level at 16-18 years, it tends to be university level)

DSP chips can do it quickly, but it's difficult and time consuming to do it manually.
Now interestingly,if you have a frequency spectrum and if you know the phases of each harmonic, you can fairly easily construct the time/voltage waveform by producing sinewaves of the differing amplitudes, frequencies and phases and simply add the waveforms all together, and the original time/voltage waveform will be constructed.

You can do this easily on a computer and plot the resultant time/voltage waveform after each different sinewave (harmonic) has been added, the result is very interesting.
Do this for a spectrum where the harmonics are: 1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15 (odd harmonics only) times the frequency of the fundamental, and the amplitude reduces 1/3 each time for each harmonic and you the summation of the harmonics will eventually construct a square wave.  It's a really useful thing to try out and you'll learn a lot more about harmonics, spectrums and waveforms in general.

Comment: thanks alot for giving very good explanation. But if u already have any any results or diagram ,can u add in the above answer to clear the concept easily? thanks in advance