# Please explain FFT Frequency Spectrum and different filters

Tags: fourier

It seems that I am not able to find the right key-words in order to get the answers from google but how can I recognize different filters based on their FFT Frequency Spectrum and how do different filter look like in their FFT Frequency Spectrum?

I understand that the FFT represents a signal as a spectrum of its frequencies but I don't really know how to interpret a Frequency Spectrum plot of a FFT. I don't know how different filters would look like such as high-pass, low-pass and band-pass filters.

Could somebody explain and/or link me to some resources that could explain that to me? Please understand that I don't need a deep mathematical explanation I just need to be able to interpret and distinguish different FFT FS plots.

Thank you!

**For example:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: What exactly is unclear in those plots? Can you maybe provide an example we can talk about? Have you looked at what the different axis represent?

Comment: There are a lot of great resources on the first page of Google or in any number of undergrad-level textbooks. You don't need us to help you find one.

Comment: @PlasmaHH In an example I have to solve I got two zero padded signals {..0,1,0,2,0,1,0,..} and {..0,1,2,1,0,..}. I have to calculate the FFT and plot the magnitude plot. I just don't understand what I see there. What kind of filters those are and what these plots tell me about their frequencies.

Comment: @Gregd'Eon Every page I can find goes into too many details for something that should be an easy question for someone who already understands this matter. I am not at all into signal processing and/or electronics etc. There must be a way to let me recognize different filters according to their FFT FS without having to read the matter of half of a semester.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try and explain things as simply as I can.

The frequency spectrum shows how the filter looks in the frequency domain.That filter is the one which is multiplied (in the frequency domain) with your input signal so you can tell what type of filter your filter is by looking at the frequencies you filter stops e.g a filter with all zeros will stop everything and one with all ones will let all frequencies pass.

For example in you image of the plot of \$H_1[k]\$, look at the frequencies greater than 0 (ignore the negative part of the graph for now - it is just a reflection of the positive side), from the graph you can see that low frequencies in the filter are stopped and higher frequencies are let through, therefore that is a high pass filter.

In the second image (again ignoring the negative parts), you can see that very low frequencies and very high frequencies are let through and only a small band of frequencies is stopped.That filter is therefore a band-stop filter.

Answer (score 1):

Stefan,  I answered someone else's question on spectrums and conversion from time domain to frequency domain a couple of days ago, if you can seek out my other posts you will find a fairly lengthy response including diagrams of sinewaves adding together and the spectrums that go with it.  I think that answer will go some way to giving you an introduction.

The maths involved in using producing an FFT from a time based representation of a signal is quite difficult, it's generally only taught at unversity level, so if you haven't studied maths, physics, engineering at university, chances are you would struggle with the maths.

Taking a FFT manually of waveform, except for the simplest of waveforms is not easy.

Here's the other question I provided a couple of answers.

[Can anybody give proof about features of phase and magnitude spectrum?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/170251/can-anybody-give-proof-about-features-of-phase-and-magnitude-spectrum/170804#170804)

You also asked about filters and how to recognise them. It's very easy. I'm attaching a single image which shows the idealised responses for low pass, band pass and high pass filters.  Ignore all the maths that's shown.

Essentially filters fall into three types passive, active and digital. Passives are made from LCR components - inductors, resistors, capacitors. Active filters are made from opamp circuits which use LCR components.  Both these types are analogue filters.

The response curves (frequeny along horizontal axis) for these real realisable filters differs from the theoretical 'ideal' response shown in the image.

[image]

Generally speaking opamp active implementations of filters enable the designer to get closer to the ideal filter response, with a steeper cutoff between the pass band and the stop band, but there are side effects which need to be understood - greater phase distortion as the cutover frequency is reached, ripples in the pass band.

Additional filter stages may be required to correct for phase anomolies introduced by an earlier active filter stage.

Digital Filters: software implementation of a filter. Beyond the scope of this to go it to here.